# C# Draw on changed pixels between two images

Tags: c#

For example, I have pic 1 and pic 2, they are same dimensions except pic 2 has a square in the top left corner. How can I compare the two pictures get the location of each pixel thats colour has changed and then draw to each pixel? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with images recently, and this is what I've been doing:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

// Open your two pictures as Bitmaps
Bitmap im1 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("file1.bmp");
Bitmap im2 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("file2.bmp");

// Assuming they're the same size, loop through all the pixels
for (int y = 0; y < im1.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < im1.Width; x++)
    {
        // Get the color of the current pixel in each bitmap
        Color color1 = im1.GetPixel(x, y);
        Color color2 = im2.GetPixel(x, y);

        // Check if they're the same
        if (color1 != color2)
        {
            // If not, generate a color...
            Color myRed = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
            // .. and set the pixel in one of the bitmaps
            im1.SetPixel(x, y, myRed);
        }
    }
}
// Save the updated bitmap to a new file
im1.Save("newfile.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

This might not be exactly what you want to do, but hopefully should give you some ideas on how to get started.

Comment: I'm at work so can't really spend time having a detailed conversation :p Have a go and see how far you can get; if you get stuck on something, leave a comment or edit your question and someone will help you out.

Comment: +1 for the approach...try this to speed it up (`GetPixel()` isn't very fast): http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the link; I didn't fancy trying to explain `LockPixels` myself

Comment: Tim, can me and you skype?